# Initiate Tab Sync From Outside Android Application (Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: android, firefox, google-chrome, tabs, synchronization

I am interested in opening either Chrome or Firefox via a separate Android application and also having that application initiate a tab sync (assume the user has already set up tag syncing in their browser). I have been unable to find a way to do this, is it possible?

Comment: You should decompile the application to see if it can handle it via an intent. Specifically you need to find out if the manifest supports that configuration. There is no other way to confirm it unless both of these  applications have written APIs that can be called via the Intent's respective data.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate the Chrome browser by invoking an explicit intent, however you can't force a tab sync.  Tab sync requires that the user has signed in to Chrome and has enabled the tab sync feature.